# My plot is not showing any curves

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I want to see what will happen for different values of the parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$, but all I see is an empty plot.

Can someone help me?

```
Manipulate[ 
 Plot[
 {
  x -> Function[{t}, 1 - (-1 + k2*E^(k1*t + k1 )) /(-1 + k1*E^(k1*t + k1 ) + k2*E^(k1*t + k1 ))]
  , u -> Function[{t}, (-1 + k2*E^(k1*t + k1) ) /(-1 + E^(k1* t + k1 ) *k1 + E^(k1 t C[1] + k1 C[1] C[2]) *k2)]
 }
 , {t, 0, 100}
 ]
 , {k1, 0, 10}
 , {k2, 0, 10}
 ]
```

Answer (score 8):

A rule ( `->` ) does not work like a function definition here.  If you instead define `x` and `u` as functions of `t`, `k1` and `k2` the plot works as you would like.  It is also useful to set the `PlotRange` so it does not automatically rescale with the function.

```
x[t_, k1_, k2_] := 
  1 - (-1 + k2*E^(k1*t + k1))/(-1 + k1*E^(k1*t + k1) + 
      k2*E^(k1*t + k1));
u[t_, k1_, k2_] := (-1 + k2*E^(k1*t + k1))/(-1 + E^(k1*t + k1)*k1 + 
    E^(k1 t C[1] + k1 C[1] C[2])*k2)

Manipulate[
  Plot[
    {x[t, k1, k2], u[t, k1, k2]}, 
    {t, 0, 100}, 
    PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
  ], 
  {k1, 0, 10}, 
  {k2, 0, 10}
]
```

[image: Manipulate]

Comment: @Iowriniak Thanks a lot!